# Is there an app for iphone that can notify me whenever my mac powers on?

Tags: iphone, applications, notifications, power

I would like to know if there was an app that can notify me whenever my mac is powered on. like IFTTT app. example if mac powered on then send a message to iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly script this. There are many approaches that would work. It depends on how comfortable you are with the various tools, and if your Mac automatically logs into a user account.

If your Mac automatically logs into your account on powering on, consider using Automator or AppleScript, and [Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76915-automation-rules-and-best-practices).

### Automator and Twitter

Consider combining this [article on Automator and Twitter](http://www.macworld.com/article/1140753/twitterautomator.html). You could send a private tweet when your account is logged in. Save the workflow as an application and add it your account's Login Items: **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups**

### Alternative Approaches

If your Mac does not automatically log into a user account, you will need to use a shell script approach. Automator and AppleScript both require an active user session.

You could use AppleScript or shell script for sending a messages or e-mail. Add [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) or a [third party tool](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) for scheduling the event on start-up or login.

This can all be integrated into [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/wtf) as a trigger.